# Hacer un mensaje para dectectar campos vacios en flutter con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter

Hola Soy en nuevo en Flutter con python, estoy haciendo un ejercicio de operaciones matemáticas. Ya me funciona todo(gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad de stackoverflow) pero quisiera recudir el código al momento de que valida si los campos están vacíos, lo controlo con 2 mensajes valor1.error_text= "por favor ingrese primer valor" ", valor2.error_text= "por favor ingrese primer valor"   quisiera reducirlo a un solo mensaje que me detecte cuando algunos de los 2 campos de texto este vació me diga "falta ingresa valor(es)". Hice modificaciones al código por sugerencia de @Jorgesys  si funciona la validación pero visualmente no muestra ningun mensaje pero por consola(mediante un print) si me muestra el mensaje. Podrian ayudarme aque el mensaje e muestre, aqui les dejo mi codigo y las imagenes:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page):

    page.title = "Operaciones Matematicas"

    error_campos = ""

    def valida_campos():
        nonlocal error_campos
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            error_campos = "falta ingresar valor(es)."
        else:
            error_campos = "" 

    def sumar(e):
        valida_campos()        
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            print(error_campos)      
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) +  int(valor2.value)) 

        page.update()

    def restar(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valor1.error_text = "por favor ingrese primer valor"
            valor2.error_text = "por favor ingrese segundo valor"       
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) -  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()  

    def multiplicar(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valor1.error_text = "por favor ingrese primer valor"
            valor2.error_text = "por favor ingrese segundo valor"       
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) *  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()

    def dividir(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valor1.error_text = "por favor ingrese primer valor"
            valor2.error_text = "por favor ingrese segundo valor"       
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) /  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()            

    page.add(ft.Text("Operaciones Matematicas", size=50, color="green"))

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor1)

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor2)
    


    page.add(
             ft.Row(controls=[valor1, valor2]),
             ft.Row(
                    controls=[
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="+", on_click = sumar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="-", on_click = restar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="*", on_click = multiplicar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="/", on_click = dividir),
                      ]    
                    )
             )      
    page.update()


    txtresultado = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(txtresultado)
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿lo que estás buscando es mostrar el mensaje dentro del entorno gráfico o solo dentro de los Text? Hay varias cosas a mejorar desde mi perspectiva, por ejemplo control de lo que se ingresa, ahora acepta caracteres y eso dará error,además como incentivo, solo sumar dos números es muy limitado, ya tenés el concepto de las operaciones, te diría que mires como funciona cualquier calculadora para que veas que te falta básicamente de implementar.
Según la documentación de Flet se pueden usar AlertDialog para mostrar mensajes, de forma común o modal.
En este caso a modo de muestra(no es la mejor forma) agrego un alerta para cada valor y lo invoco desde todas las funciones.   Traté de modificar lo menos posible el código.

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

import flet as ft
from flet import * 

def main(page):

    page.title = "Operaciones Matemáticas"
    
    def mostrar_valor1(event):
        page.dialog = dlg_valor1
        dlg_valor1.open = True
        page.update()    
    
    def cerrar_msg1(event):
        dlg_valor1.open = False
        page.update()    

    dlg_valor1 = ft.AlertDialog(
        modal=True, 
        title=ft.Text("Atención"),
        content=ft.Text("Falta ingresar el valor 1"), 
        actions=[
            ft.TextButton("De acuerdo", on_click=cerrar_msg1)],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END)
    
    
    def cerrar_msg2(event):
        dlg_valor2.open = False
        page.update()
    
    dlg_valor2 = ft.AlertDialog(
        modal=True,
        title=ft.Text("Atención"),
        content=ft.Text("Falta ingresar el valor 2"),
        actions=[
            ft.TextButton("De acuerdo", on_click=cerrar_msg2)],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END)
 
    
        
    def mostrar_valor2(event):
        page.dialog = dlg_valor2
        dlg_valor2.open = True
        page.update()    
        
    def valida_campos():
        if valor1.value == "":
            mostrar_valor1(event)
            return 
            
        if valor2.value == "":
            mostrar_valor2(event)
            return 
    
    
 
    def sumar(e):
                
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valida_campos()      
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) +  int(valor2.value)) 

        page.update()

    def restar(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valida_campos()    
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) -  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()  

    def multiplicar(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valida_campos()       
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) *  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()

    def dividir(e):
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            valida_campos()     
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) /  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()            

    page.add(ft.Text("Operaciones Matematicas", size=50, color="green"))

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor1)

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor2)
    


    page.add(
             ft.Row(controls=[valor1, valor2]),
             ft.Row(
                    controls=[
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="+", on_click = sumar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="-", on_click = restar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="*", on_click = multiplicar),
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="/", on_click = dividir),
                      ]    
                    )
             )      
    page.update()


    txtresultado = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(txtresultado)
    page.update()

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)
```

me parece fácil que distingas las funciones de cada mensaje porque están individualizadas.
De ahí saqué el código:
https://flet.dev/docs/controls/alertdialog

Comment: Gracias @tincopasan

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una función para validar si los campos son vacíos, almacena el mensaje de error en una variable y este puedes asignarlo a `valor1.error_text` y `valor2.error_text` cuando la función detecte que hay campos vacios.

```
import flet as ft

def main(page):

    page.title = "Operaciones Matematicas"


     #---------------------------------
    error_campos = ""

    def valida_campos():
        nonlocal error_campos
        if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
            error_campos = "falta ingresa valor(es)."
        else:
            error_campos = ""

     #---------------------------------

    def sumar(e):
        valida_campos()        
        if error_campos:
            valor1.error_text = error_campos
            valor2.error_text = error_campos
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) +  int(valor2.value)) 

        page.update()

    def restar(e):
        valida_campos()        
        if error_campos:
            valor1.error_text = error_campos
            valor2.error_text = error_campos
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) -  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()  

    def multiplicar(e):
        valida_campos()        
        if error_campos:
            valor1.error_text = error_campos
            valor2.error_text = error_campos     
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) *  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()

    def dividir(e):
        valida_campos()        
        if error_campos:
            valor1.error_text = error_campos
            valor2.error_text = error_campos     
        else:
            valor1.error_text= ''
            valor2.error_text= ''
            txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) /  int(valor2.value))

        page.update()            

    page.add(ft.Text("Operaciones Matematicas", size=50, color="green"))

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor1)

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="green", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor2)
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: hice tu sugerencia pero igual sigue sin validar los campos

Comment: Si no escribes texto en los campos, no se válida correctamente con el código que te proporcioné? @AndresVilca

Comment: asi es, no escribo texto en los campos y me sigue saliendo los mensajes de valor1 y valor2